# Find missing entry at different time period

Tags: r, dataframe

I am processing a data frame with two columns:

```
portfolio    date      stock    Value
1           200006     Apple    10
1           200006     Google   20
1           200006     IBM      30
1           200007     Apple    10
```

Because the amount of data is large, I want to find a simple way to check from date June 2000 to July 2000, within portfolio 1, both stock Google and IBM are missing. The return would be a c("IBM","GOOGLE"). I will use the information what stocks are not listed in July 2000 and get these stocks' value in June 2000 to balance the portfolio in July 2000. So in this case, I hope to get c("IBM","GOOGLE") and then get their values (20,30) to do further adjustment for Apple's value 10.

The data type for four columns are: factor, Integer, factor and Integer for portfolio, date, stock and Value.

Is there any function or package that can deal with this problem?

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I just add some more background to describe the problem. It is just one step of a complicate project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
# Get all possible stocks
stocks <- unique(df$stock)

# Get missing stocks
df[, stocks[!stocks %in% stock], .(portfolio, date)]
#    portfolio   date     V1
# 1:         1 200007 Google
# 2:         1 200007    IBM

# Or vector output (no date or portfolio info)
df[, stocks[!stocks %in% stock], .(portfolio, date)]$V1
# [1] "Google" "IBM"
```

Comment: That is great! Thanks for your idea!